# CSS não obedece a margin-right

Tags: css

Eu simplesmente não percebo porque é que a terceira linha não fica alinhada com o resto do texto.
http://jsfiddle.net/Ra35L/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="contact"><h1>CONTACTO</h1>
    <p>+(351) 968 888 888&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+(351) 218 888 888<br><br>
    <a href="mailto:uas@tet.com" target="_blank">linguas@tetraling.com</a><br><br>
    Avenida da República, Torre Soleil

</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
#contact {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #449DCC;
    height: 350px;
}
#contact h1 {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18
}
#contact p {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color:#fff;
}
#contact a {
    float: right;
    font-size: 15px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: todo é resto é para que lado? Esquerda ou direita?

Comment: É tudo encostado à direita

Comment: Eu sugiro evitar `<br />`(s) e espaços dessa maneira... é isto que procura? __http://jsfiddle.net/Ra35L/3/__

Comment: Exactamente, mas porque é que os '<br>' prejudica essas formatações?

Comment: @Miguel, respondí em baixo, mais detalhado do que teria espaço aqui nos comentários.

Comment: Para você ver neh, ninguém consegue colocar um mente pensante no stackoverflow pt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a propriedade `text-align`. [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ra35L/6/), que simplesmente alinha todo texto na posição que você especificar (direita, esquerda ou centro)

```
#contact p {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 15px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Obgado, parece-me ser a resposta mais lógica apesar de todas resultarem. http://jsfiddle.net/Ra35L/9/

Answer (score 0):

***Coloque um `<p>texto</p>` para cada linha***

```
<div id="contact">
    <h1>CONTACTO</h1>
    <p>(351) 967 181 237&nbsp;(351) 214 569 018</p>
    <p><a href="mailto:linguas@tetraling.com" target="_blank">linguas@tetraling.com</a></p>
    <p>Avenida da República, Torre Soleil</p>
</div>
```

*Link:* http://jsfiddle.net/Ra35L/5/

Comment: Muito obgado. Porque é que os '<br>' prejudica a formatação?

Comment: Na verdade não prejudica, mas, geralmente a gente faz `<br />` em texto maiores ... tags assim fica organizado com `p`

Answer (score 0):

Penso que o que pretendes é este resultado:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ra35L/4/)

```
<div id="contact"><h1>CONTACTO</h1>
   <p>+(351) 967 181 237&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+(351) 214 569 018<br><br></p>
   <a href="mailto:linguas@tetraling.com" target="_blank">linguas@tetraling.com</a><br><br>
   <p>Avenida da República, Torre Soleil</p>

</div>
```

.

```
#contact a {
    float: right;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**O que fiz?**

Fechei o `<p>` antes do `<a>` e abri de novo no fim do `</a>`; Coloquei `margin-right: 25px;` no CSS `#contact a` para ficar tudo bem alinhado.